# Floating shelf limits

Tags: structural, load-bearing, shelf

I have a 12 foot tall alcove section that I would like to use to install a total of 3 or 4 floating shelves made of pine (each shelf 42 inches long, 12 inch deep, 2.5 inch thick). I have a total of 3 vertical studs available to mount each shelf. While there are various shelving brackets available, I'd like to keep it simple and use hanger bolts (1/2 inch diameter, 10 inch total length, 3 inch wood thread on one side and 2.5 inch machine thread on the other, although the machine thread does not matter as it gets inserted into the shelf; overall there will be 7 inches of bolt inside the shelf). I don't envision more than 150 lbs on each shelf (including the shelf but the total is a very generous over-estimate). I presume I should be safe, but just don't know how to compute the loads on the shelves. Would there be a significant difference installing 3 vs 4 shelves given the overall load on the framing in that alcove section?

Comment: 4 shelfs with 150 lbs each is 600 lbs. Divided on the 3 studs is is 200 lbs per stud. Divided by 3 anchors/screws per shelf it is 50-60 lbs per screw.

Comment: when using such long screws, be sure you will not hit any services that are inside the wall, like water, electricity, gas or data.

Comment: _You_ may not envision more than 150lbs on each shelf, but someone else may decide to load them up. Also, 42" of hardback books get pretty heavy pretty quickly.